# Pandas and Matplotlib - how can I change plot area to fit in more x-axis text?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pandas, graphing

Say I read in this csv file into a pandas dataframe:

File contents:

> ```
> Strings, Values, Letters
> Made up data, 55.0, A
> with long text strings for index, 125.5, B
> with long text strings for index, 85.5, B
> how does one, 1.3, A
> how does one, 12.3, A
> change the plot area to, 96.1, B
> fit all of this text in?, 0.2, B
> fit all of this text in?, 47.2, B
> ```

Code:

```
c=pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
```

Gives:

> ```
>                             Strings   Values  Letters
> 0                      Made up data     55.0        A
> 1  with long text strings for index    125.5        B
> 2  with long text strings for index     85.5        B
> 3                      how does one      1.3        A
> 4                      how does one     12.3        A
> 5           change the plot area to     96.1        B
> 6          fit all of this text in?      0.2        B
> 7          fit all of this text in?     47.2        B
> ```

I then use `groupby` to sum the strings:

```
g=c.groupby(u'Strings').sum()
```

Giving:

> ```
>                                    Values
> Strings                                  
> Made up data                         55.0
> change the plot area to              96.1
> fit all of this text in?             47.4
> how does one                         13.6
> with long text strings for index    211.0
> ```

And finally plot like so:

```
g.plot(kind='bar')
```

Giving:

[image]

As you can see the x axis text is badly cropped. How can I fix this?

Note that I have tried using the `rot` parameter (e.g. `rot=-45`) but this is insufficient.

I imagine that a solution might involve setting the plot area but I'm unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried: plt.tight_layout()